# Вывод данных из бд отдельный участок таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Ребята, вывожу данные из таблицы, но пишет в одну строку все, необходимо что бы данные с utm_term выносились в отдельную участок, а именно SubID2, как реализовать подскажите. Спасибо

---

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<th>SubID1</th>';
echo '<th>Количество</th>';
echo '<th>SubID2</th>';
echo '<th>Количество</th>';
mysql_query("SELECT distinct stolbets1 FROM tablename UNION SELECT distinct stolbets2 FROM tablename");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT `utm_campaign`, COUNT(`utm_campaign`) AS cnt FROM `test_table` GROUP BY `utm_campaign` UNION SELECT `utm_term`, COUNT(`utm_term`) AS cnk FROM `test_table` GROUP BY `utm_term`  ",$connect_to_db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

{



echo  "

<tr>
<td>".$row['utm_campaign']."</td>
<td>  ".$row['cnt']."</td>

<td>".$row['utm_term']."</td>
<td>  ".$row['cnk']."</td>

</tr>"; 

}
echo '</table>';
echo '</thead>';
mysql_close($connect_to_db);
?>
<code lang="php">
```

Comment: Ну вам в первую очередь надо, что бы SQL запрос возвращал данные для левой и правой частей таблицы в одной записи. union для этого совершенно не подходит. Но что бы сделать такой SQL-запрос как минимум надо знать ваши данные и по какому принципу соотносить данные из двух таблиц, Т.е. при какоих условиях запись из таблицы 2 должна лечь в одну строку с записью из таблицы 1

Comment: Примером есть ссылка - http://example.com?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=test&utm_content=dopinfa&utm_campaign=kamapnisa
Данные меток записались в БД, далее я вывожу 2 значения из одной записи.
В результате будет отображения должно быть в левой часте запись - kamapnisa и ее количество.

Comment: А во второй test и колличество

Comment: По вашей ссылке ничего толкового не открывается

Comment: Вы просто свой sql запрос выполните в чем угодно и обратите внимание, что сейчас данные из одной и из другой таблицы - отдельные строки и на одной итерации цикла в переменные ну ни как не попадут

Comment: Если данные связаны - надо выбрать из базы вместе, одной строкой. Если не связаны - сделать на странице 2 параллельно идущие таблицы, которые заполнить по отдельности.

Comment: Сейчас попытаюсь, спасибо